# Pass through API pages with PYTHON and JSON

Tags: python, json, api

This is my API FULL OUTPUT - JSON file

```
    "took": 150,
    "total": 3377,
    "hits": [{
            Extra - not relevant JSON information
        },
        {    
            Extra - not relevant JSON information
        },
        .......
```

total - mean total amount of posts.

API limit to 250 posts per request

I need to pass through the pages and get all the posts, and then write to the single JSON file.

What I have:

This is how I pull data from API:
def post_puller():

```
apiUrl = "https://XXXX.XXXX.com/1.0/projects/{}/inbox/search.json".format(config.project_id)

json={
    'metrics': ['doc','impression','reach','engagement','repost'],
    'flag': {'rt': False},
    'focuses': [{'id':XXXXX, 'include': True}],
    'from': '{c.date_from}'.format(c=config),
    'to': '{c.date_to}'.format(c=config),
    'tz': '{c.tz}'.format(c=config),
    "start": 0,
    'limit': 250
}

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer {k.token}'.format(k=key)
    }

response = requests.post(url = apiUrl, headers=headers, json=json)
result = response.text

with open(config.data, "w+") as op:
    op.write(result.encode("utf-8"))
```

This is my python code which gets the data, modified it and writes to the file:

```
def modify_file_emoji(FILE_NAME,OUTPUT):

    print("Ready to remove issues from {} file".format(OUTPUT))

    jsonFile = open(FILE_NAME, "r")
    data = json.load(jsonFile)
    jsonFile.close()

    #Modify JSON File, that BQ will accept it.
    with open(OUTPUT, "w+") as outfileJSON:
        outfileJSON.write(json.dumps(data['hits']))

    with open(OUTPUT, "r") as infileInsight:
        insightData = infileInsight.read()\
        .replace("","")\

    with open(OUTPUT, "w+") as outfileInsight:
        outfileInsight.write(insightData)


    print("File: {} modified - removed all the known issues".format(OUTPUT))
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? This is just a collection of statements currently. Do you get an error?

Comment: @roganjosh I do not know what is the way to pass through the API pages if I have 3377 posts, but I can view only 250 (limit) per request, what is the way to get posts 251-500, 501-750 and so on???

Comment: @roganjosh I know to get variable as total posts I can use - json.dumps(data['total']) , but not sure how to create a loop which will pass through API pages.